# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxx.yyy'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to python programing and django.. I have not found any resources addressing this issue on web hence reaching out community.

I have a django rest api with following code **MyApi.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyOwnView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'some': 'data'})
```

My module is not found in the url.py file, below is url.py file And **urls.py** file is here:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from jpbapi.api.MyApi import MyOwnView
urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This fails loading my module please see my project structure below, not sure where i am wrong.

[image]

Comment: Write `from api.MyApi import MyOwnView` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your app in settings.py -> INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    api
]
```

Then

```
from api.MyApi import MyownView
```